# What the JobScheduler stats indicate

Tags: android, adb, android-jobscheduler, dumpsys

I have a repeating job scheduled using JobScheduler API in Android 7.0.

Please help me understand the following output of command:

`adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler`

**u0a66 / < pkg >: 58x pending 5% 52x active**

Answer (score 0):

**58 pending jobs, and 5 % (of total 52 running tasks) completed.** /* 5 percent completed jobs id are stored in CompletedJobs queue to track */

```
adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler >> output.txt 
gedit output.txt //read the complete output to get concepts
```

Commonly **x** is used to represent a number (how frequently).

I have an output something as below:

```
   Current stats at 2017-07-25-01-42-38 (-5m30s657ms) over +5m30s657ms:
      1000 / android: 2x pending 1x active 
 u0a14 / com.google.android.gms: 1x pending 1% 1x active-top
      u0a66 / com.google.android.apps.photos: 3x pending 1x active
      Max concurrency: 3 total, 1 foreground
```

**Syntax:**

```
 /*<Uid> <reference> <app_name>: <% completed> <pending_jobs_count> <% completed>
     <active_jobs_count> <status_that_tells_if_active_job_is_at_top_of_queue> */
```

**It is a general understanding of how it should be. I can't provide you the link, so I am also not 100% certain. I just shared you my view.**

JobScheduler is to effectively maintain the concurrency (from thread level -- called jobs). Even for the same program, there can be multiple processes (eg, service can start from the different process), and several threads. Ultimately these all threads are put in ThreadPoolExecuter and their operations are scheduled.

Comment: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox: 1x pending 2% 1x active . you mean jobScheduler knows the progress of job. i don't agree

Comment: @ArnavM.  
com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, this part is the job name. As you can see structure similar to package.package.package.

Comment: @ArnavM., I don't have an exact link that I can provide to you. It is showing general information.

Comment: i don't need a link, just justify your definition

Comment: @ArnavM., I provided a solution of what you asked.

Comment: oh okay.. % doesn't mean the percentage?

Comment: @ArnavM., active jobs are in the ActiveJobs queue. They are being processed in different cores in pseudo parallelism way. Once each jobs gets processed and it completes, the job gets removed from ActiveJobs queue to CompletedJobs queue. % doesn't say tracking inside a particular jobs. % says tracking the CompletedJobs queue. In my view, it should be (completedJobsQueue / ActiveJobsQueue) * 100 percent.

Comment: @ArnavM., why don't you agree that jobscheduler can't track how many jobs it completed processing?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Uddhav ..but its more confusing now with what "Alex" has answered.

Comment: @Alex answers are true. Basically we said the same thing. Job scheduler can track how many completed, how many pending, how many active, which are active top among those active jobs etc. He explained in terms of duration regarding %. It's still the same thing. I don't understand your dislike on my answer. I just wanted to help you. If I find the link, I will modify my answer.

Comment: Would you please up (like) my answer? You don't need to accept this as answer until I provide proof link.

Comment: i didn't downvote, it's not chat forum, i appreciate your help

Answer (score -1):

The *job* can be in `pending`, `active` and `active-top` state.

The `u0a66 / package.name: 58x pending 5% 52x active` line means that during that specified *duration* the `package.name` has `58` jobs in the `pending` state (which have been `pending` for less than 0.5% of the duration total), `52` jobs in the `active` state (which have been `active` for 5% of the duration total) and `0` jobs in the `active-top` state.